# StringVar().set() Not Adjusting StringVar

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner learning Python and mucking around with the tkinter GUI stuff. I'm trying to make a very basic beginner project that allows a user to type something into a text box and click a button, whereupon that input is added to a label in another part of the window.

However, I'm running into an issue where the StringVar that I'm using as an output isn't being updated by the .set() command.

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Terminal Writer 9000!")
        self.terminalString = StringVar()
        self.terminalString.set("This is an example message.")
        self.allcontent = ttk.Frame(self.window)
        self.allcontent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwse")
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.allcontent)
        self.mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nwse", columnspan=4, rowspan=5)
        self.terminal = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, textvariable=self.terminalString, padding=10, relief="sunken") 
        self.terminal.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=2, sticky="nwse")
        # GUI setup for Buttons and Entry box omitted...

play = TerminalWriterApp()
play.window.mainloop()
```

However, the area used by the terminal Label is blank, even though it should display "This is an example message." While troubleshooting, I made this, which is basically a complete copy/paste of the functional elements of my original code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()

strvar = StringVar()
strvar.set("Test 2")

allcontent = ttk.Frame(window)
allcontent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwse")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(allcontent)
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwse", columnspan=4, rowspan=5)

text = Label(mainframe, text="Test 1")
text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwse")

text2 = Label(mainframe, textvariable=strvar)
text2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nwse")

window.mainloop()
```

This code functions as intended, displaying a window with "Test 1" and "Test 2" on separate lines.

Does anyone know why the set() method wouldn't work in this context? (Also, feel free to get mad at my horrible code - I need to learn good habits somehow!)

Comment: Is your master window in your first example the right one? self.terminal seems to be attached to self.mainframe

Comment: Your first code block works as expected in my Windows machine running Python 3.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, the label appears when the app takes focus (when you click on it); maybe it is because of the stack nested frames, IDK.

You could use `focus_force` to constrain the OS to give focus to your app immediately.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class TerminalWriterApp:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Terminal Writer 9000!")

        self.terminalString = StringVar()
        self.terminalString.set("This is an example message.")

        self.allcontent = ttk.Frame(self.window)
        self.allcontent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nwse")

        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.allcontent)
        self.mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nwse", columnspan=4, rowspan=5)

        self.terminal = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, textvariable=self.terminalString, padding=10, relief="sunken") 
        self.terminal.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=5, columnspan=2, sticky="nwse")

        self.terminal.focus_force()

play = TerminalWriterApp()
play.window.mainloop()
```